# Amazon Textract without using Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I want to extract information from PDFs using Amazon Textract (as in [How to use the Amazon Textract with PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038306/how-to-use-the-amazon-textract-with-pdf-files)). All the answers and the AWS documentation requires the input to be Amazon S3 objects.

Can I use Textract without uploading the PDFs to Amazon S3, but just giving them in the REST call? (I have to store the PDFs locally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this question with the Java API in mind. The short answer is Yes.

If you look at this **TextractAsyncClient** Javadoc for a given operation:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/textract/TextractAsyncClient.html#analyzeDocument-software.amazon.awssdk.services.textract.model.AnalyzeDocumentRequest-

It states:

" **Documents for asynchronous operations can also be in PDF format**"

This means - you can reference a PDF document and create an **AnalyzeDocumentRequest**  object like this (without pulling from an Amazon S3 bucket). :

```
public static void analyzeDoc(TextractClient textractClient, String sourceDoc) {

        try {
            InputStream sourceStream = new FileInputStream(new File(sourceDoc));
            SdkBytes sourceBytes = SdkBytes.fromInputStream(sourceStream);

            // Get the input Document object as bytes
            Document myDoc = Document.builder()
                    .bytes(sourceBytes)
                    .build();

            List<FeatureType> featureTypes = new ArrayList<FeatureType>();
            featureTypes.add(FeatureType.FORMS);
            featureTypes.add(FeatureType.TABLES);

            AnalyzeDocumentRequest analyzeDocumentRequest = AnalyzeDocumentRequest.builder()
                    .featureTypes(featureTypes)
                    .document(myDoc)
                    .build();

// Use the TextractAsyncClient to perform an operation like analyzeDocument

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @smac2020. Is this also possible in R or Python?

Comment: Yes - AWS supports a Python SDK. See here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/python (there is no R SDK however)

Comment: Yes, there is an R package "PAWS" that allows access to the textract API.

Answer (score 2):

I would love to be proven wrong, but as of August 2023 this is not possible.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Operations.html), all the async methods (*StartDocumentAnalysis*, *StartDocumentTextDetection*, *StartExpenseAnalysis* and *StartLendingAnalysis*) need a **required** argument called `DocumentLocation`.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_DocumentLocation.html) again, `DocumentLocation` needs information about an S3 object.

```json
   "DocumentLocation": { 
      "S3Object": { 
         "Bucket": "string",
         "Name": "string",
         "Version": "string"
      }
   }
```

Comment: The synchronous operations support single page PDFs without S3. The async operations support multi-page PDFs but they have to be stored on S3.

Comment: I think you're right...